# Strange behaviour of math-mode starred command

Tags: math-mode, starred-version

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\2}{\@ifstar{\hspace{2pt}}{\hspace{-2pt}}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\@ifstar{\,}{}\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
$$a\dd*x\2*b.$$
\end{document}
```

What I expect to get from this is the equivalent of `$$a\,\mathrm{d}x\hspace{2pt}b.$$`. Instead, I get:

[image]

Which looks like an equivalent of `$$a\mathrm{d}*x\hspace{2pt}b.$$`. Why doesn't the starred version of `\dd` behave as expected?

Comment: `\@ifstar` is described in my [“Introduzione”](https://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf), section 3.6. Of course there is a much better way to define a macro for the differential without needing a *-form: `\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`

Comment: @egreg The only problem I found with that is in case you need to write differentials like the physicist do. `\int dx f(x)`.

Comment: @Manuel If you want to use wrong notation, then take the burden on you.

Comment: @egreg I don't use it, but sometimes it's useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It behaves as expected if your expectations are correct. `\@ifstar` checks if the first non white space token after its two arguments is a `*`

in

```
\newcommand{\dd}{\@ifstar{\,}{}\mathrm{d}}
```

that means it always checks if `\mathrm` is a `*`

Compare with

```
\newcommand{\dd}{\@ifstar{\,\mathrm{d}}}{\mathrm{d}}}
```